# Evaluation of a Variable Coefficient PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to render the solution of the following partial differential equation:

$$
u = u(x,y)~;\quad
\frac1{x^{2/3}}\partial_xu
+ x^3\partial_yu
+ \partial_y^2u
+ \partial_x^3u
= 0
$$

However, the kernel seems to not produce anything. I checked documentation for different ways of inputting in the equation, but nothing helps. I even tried the sample problems directly from the documentation and those still had no explicit solution. I also quit the local kernel and repeated the process twice. I used something of the following:

```
eqn2 = D[u[x, y], {x, 3}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] + x^3 D[u[x, y], y] + 
1/x^(2/3) D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] == 0;

DSolve[eqn2, u, {x, y}]
```

Any ideas of what is going on?

Comment: The solution of your PDE can not be determined without boundary conditions. You should specify them.

Comment: I would be surprised if this can be solved by Mathematica with DSolve. Do you need an analytic solution or would it be enough if you have it numerically solved?

Comment: Yeah, it is rare that a PDE admits an analytical solution. Did you check handbooks for this particular PDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know Mathematica can only solve very special cases of partial differential equations exactly. However, since you want to *render the solution*, a numerical solution will be enough. Here's an example using the heat equation as a placeholder:

```
(* Differential equation *)
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] - D[u[x, t], x, x];
(* Boundary/Initial conditions:
   Absorbing boundaries, Gaussian bump *)
ic = {
    u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2],
    u[-10, t] == u[10, t] == Exp[-10^2/2]
};
(* Unleash the fury *)
s = NDSolve[{eqn == 0}~Join~ic, u, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 20}];
(* Visualize result *)
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. s], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

> [image]

`NDSolve` does not care about the type of differential equation, so your variable coefficients aren't a problem (modulo numerical instabilities of course). Replace `eqn` by your equation and add according initial conditions and you'll be fine. Here's an example of the same equation, only that now the diffusion constant is not $1$ but $e^{-t/3}$, making diffusion disappear over a time scale of $3$:

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] - E^(-t/3) D[u[x, t], x, x];
ic = {
    u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2],
        u[-10, t] == u[10, t] == Exp[-10^2/2]
    };
s = NDSolve[{eqn == 0}~Join~ic, u, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 20}];
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. s], {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 20}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 8, PlotPoints -> 32]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping on a analytic solution I guess. What I was really trying to do is check my solution that I obtained by hand. I guess I could equate things and check it with the numerical value given by `NDSolve`.

Comment: Just take the wave equation as an example,  which is a really easy PDE: $u_{xx}-u_{tt}=0$. It has either a useless solution, $u=\phi(x-t)+\phi(x+t)$, or one that is already too long for this comment if you want to incorporate Cauchy boundary conditions. Yours will be a lot messier I assume.

Comment: You should discuss this in the chat, comments aren't reallly suitable for things like these - it's kind of a new question you're asking there.

Comment: Can you join here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2885/solution-plots

Comment: We can delete the recent comments

Comment: @ David: Did you see the link for the chat room I posted?